# Serialise list of objects to single JSON object, with property as key:value

Tags: json.net

```
Public Class Doc

    Public TypeDoc As String = ""
    Public Property UserFields As New List(Of UserField)

End Class

Public Class UserField
    Property Name As String = ""
    Property Value As String = ""
End Class

Public Class Example

    Public Sub test()
        Dim d As New Doc
        d.TypeDoc = "Order"
        d.UserFields.Add(New UserField With {.Name = "U_Name", .Value = "Jonny"})
        d.UserFields.Add(New UserField With {.Name = "U_Surname", .Value = "Goodman"})

        Dim Ret As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Desired result "Ret":

```
{
  "TypeDoc": "Order",
  "U_Name": "Jonny",
  "U_Surname": "Goodman",
}
```

I hope you understand the example, I was wondering if it was possible to have this result.
Thank you

Comment: It would be much easier to use [`[JsonExtensionData]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeExtensionData.htm) for this purpose.  Replace `UserFields` with `<JsonExtensionData> Public Property UserFields As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)`, then add your names and values to the dictionary.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/q4O4IG